# Integrate Discourse with ASP.NET membership tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, discourse

Is it possible to integrate the Discourse forum software (http://www.discourse.org/) with my asp.net membership tables?
Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [omniauth strategy](http://meta.discourse.org/t/brand-new-plugin-interface/8793/29?u=zogstrip) or use cookie-based auth and [amend the current user logic](http://meta.discourse.org/t/amending-current-user-logic-in-discourse/10278?u=zogstrip).

It might be easier if you application already supports [OpenId](http://meta.discourse.org/t/brand-new-plugin-interface/8793?u=zogstrip).